# Makefile on different folders

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I know it has already been discussed a lot, but I'm getting a bit crazy and cannot figured it out by myself.

I'm trying to learn how to create makefiles, and I'm having problems in defining a makefile for files in different folders.

This is what I would like to obtain, after compiling:

```
/makefile
/test.exe
/src/factorials.cpp
/src/main.cpp
/src/hello.cpp
/obj/factorials.o
/obj/main.o
/obj/hello.o
/include/functions.h
```

What is wrong with this makefile?

```
C++ = g++
FILENAME = test
SOURCES_PATH = src/
SRC = $(SOURCES_PATH)factorial.cpp $(SOURCES_PATH)main.cpp $(SOURCES_PATH)hello.cpp
OBJ = factorial.o main.o hello.o

all: test.exe

test.exe: $(OBJ)
$(C++) $(OBJ) -o $(FILENAME) -Iinclude

%.o: 
$(C++) -c $(SOURCES_PATH)$*.cpp -Iinclude

clean:
rm -f test.exe
```

Everything goes correctly, but it gives me error trying to compile `src/all.cpp`. Besides, I don't know how to say to g++ to put .o files into `obj/` folder.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may make `obj/` the working folder, and set `$(vpath)` to `src/`. also depending on where your makefile actually resides, simply writing `OBJ = obj/factorial.o obj/main.o obj/hello.o` and setting `vpath` may also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I was able to obtain the result by using the following makefile

```
C++ = g++
FILENAME = test
OBJS = obj/factorial.o obj/hello.o obj/main.o
INC = -Iinclude/
vpath+= src

$(FILENAME): $(OBJS)
    $(C++) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(INC)

obj/%.o: %.cpp
    $(C++) -o $@ -c $< $(INC)

all: $(FILENAME)

clean:
    rm -rf objs/*.o *~ $(FILENAME).exe
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your `.o` rule as follows

```
obj/%.o: $(SOURCES_PATH)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Alternatively [`$(vpath)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) can be used to resolve where `make` looks up the source (prerequisite) files for a target:

```
vpath += $(SOURCES_PATH)

obj/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: I don't know why, but with your code I got `no rule to make target obj/factorial.o`...